# 2 Slicer in same Power BI dashboard is not working properly

Tags: filter, powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, slicers

In my dashboard There is a matrix. In that first column is product. And the rest of the columns are Week1, Week2, Week3 upto week 52. Values in these columns are price of products in each week.

I need to apply 2 seperate slicer of same thing. That is slicer values are week1, week2...week52.

If I select week 3 from first slicer then matrix should show values on week3 only. And then I select week 10 from second slicer. Then matrix should show both week 3 and week 10 values only.

Is there any way to do this.?

When I applied both slicer then last slicer only applied. First I selected slicer1 and applied week3 then matrix showed only week3 prices. Then I selected week10 from second slicer. Then matrix showed week10 prices only and slicer1 also automatically selected week10. I want to select distinct options from both slicer and its corresponding values.